# cvdoubleitem in modernCV when using recent LyX version

Tags: lyx, moderncv, cv

I would like to ask how to use the *cvdoubleitem* in moderncv in (recent version) of LyX. I use the cvdoubleitem for listing my computer skills exactly as [displayed in this example](http://mirror.unicorncloud.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template_casual_orange.pdf).

I created a minimal LyX example:

```
 #LyX 2.1 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 474
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass moderncv
\begin_preamble
% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
% possible themes are "classic" and "casual"
% optional argument are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'grey' and 'roman' (for roman fonts, instead of sans serif fonts)

% required
\firstname{Max}
% required
\familyname{Mustermann}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_math auto
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 2
\tocdepth 2
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
maketitle
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
Test
\end_layout

\begin_layout DoubleItem
Category1 item Category2 item
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

I can see, that instead of:

```
 \cvdoubleitem{Category1}{item}{Category2}{item}
```

Lyx creates following LaTeX code:

```
\cvdoubleitem{}{}{}{Category1 item Category2 item}
```

This was already discussed in [Latex Community forum](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=25276&p=93690), sadly I do not understand the solution mentioned in the end of the discussion. Could someone give me a better explanation ? Of course I could insert the right LaTeX command for cvdoubleitem in LyX, but than I could give up on using LyX at all.

Comment: double entry of what? How can I reproduce the problem starting from File > Open > Examples > modernCV ? I do not see any duplicates when compiling that.

Comment: I appologize, I ment \cvdoubleitem I corrected my question

Comment: Please write a complete question. It is good to reference outside links for background, but at SE we like to have questions self-contained. Please also give a minimal example .lyx file so we can reproduce the problem and thus try to help you.

Comment: I edited my original question, added minimal LyX example and explained the difference in the Latex output.

Comment: thanks for the example, I think I understand what is going on now and will make an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put the cursor in the double item paragraph and go to Insert > Left Summary, or Insert > Left Text, or Insert > Right Summary. When you insert text in those boxes they will fill in the other LaTeX arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much. Left summary, left Text, right summary and than a plain text creates the right LaTeX Syntax. Is this sort of workaround or a propper way to create the cvdoubleitem ?

Comment: This is the correct way. This is how LyX inserts LaTeX arguments. Note that if you are in a different paragraph environment, there will be different argument options listed under Insert.